# How to take a screenshot by web scraping code (Selenium) in Databricks for Azure?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, databricks, azure-databricks

I'm starting in the world of web scraping. my try is so simple. I'm download and installing firefox. Then, I start by going to a google, and just to confirm this code is working I'm trying to take a screenshot and save it into a temporary path in order to display at the end.

Unfortunately, when I execute the code nothing seems to be wrong, but when it finish, I just get an image totally in blank as follow:

[image]

My code is is described down below:

Installing Selenium CMD:

```
!pip install selenium 
!pip install webdriver-manager
```

Firefox download and installing in temporary path CMD:

```
%sh 
wget https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/106.0.1/linux-x86_64/en-US/firefox-106.0.1.tar.bz2 -O /tmp/firefox.tar.bz2
%sh 
tar -xvf /tmp/firefox.tar.bz2 -C /tmp/
%sh 
sudo apt-get update -y
%sh 
sudo apt-get install -y wget bzip2 libxtst6 libgtk-3-0 libx11-xcb-dev libdbus-glib-1-2 libxt6 libpci-dev libudev-dev
%sh
rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

Algorithm CMD:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager
import time
from IPython.display import Image

# Temporary path
screenshot_path = '/tmp/web.png'

# Firefox controller configuration
service = Service(executable_path=GeckoDriverManager().install()) 
options = Options()
options.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)
options.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
options.set_preference("browser.download.dir", '/tmp/head_count_data/')
options.headless = False
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.binary_location = '/tmp/firefox/firefox'
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options, service=service)
login_url = "https://www.google.com/"

time.sleep(20)

# Screenshot
driver.save_screenshot(screenshot_path)

time.sleep(20)

# Show results
Image(filename=screenshot_path)
```

**Could you tell me what I'm doing wrong?** I've tried many times, I restarted the kernel, changed image format to .jpg and I checked out I've got installed PIL library by using (where I've got 9.2 version in the results).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on provided information it seems the issue is that you are not passing the `URL` to the `Driver`.

Below is an updated code snippet:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager
import time
from IPython.display import Image

# Temporary path
screenshot_path = '/tmp/web.png'

# Firefox controller configuration
service = Service(executable_path=GeckoDriverManager().install()) 
options = Options()
options.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)
options.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
options.set_preference("browser.download.dir", '/tmp/head_count_data/')

options.add_argument('--headless')
options.headless = False
options.binary_location = '/tmp/firefox/firefox'
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options, service=service)
login_url = "https://www.google.com/"

driver.get(login_url) #Pass the login_url to driver
time.sleep(20)

# Screenshot
driver.save_screenshot(screenshot_path)

time.sleep(20)
driver.quit()
# Show results
Image(filename=screenshot_path)
```

With this modified code I was able to get the output.
[image]

Comment: You're such a genius it worked. thanks.